# In Umbraco, how do a set a page or package to default?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco.. I installed Runway, then I installed the creative be package.

http://localhost/home.aspx takes me to the crative website, whereas http://localhost/ me to the Runway site.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya Greg as I created the Creaite Site wizard it is not intended to run with Runway installed. They are two different concepts.

Runway is a quick wire frame soilution to get you up and runnign quickly using common modules, where as my site wizard is used as a demo of a basic site on umbraco and is used to help you learn/understand all the components work together.

In regards to your original question having multiple root nodes is possible, but it is intended for having multi lingual sites mainly.

On each root/site node right click it and add hostname which you can add a hostname to that root node.

For example

home UK node --> assign hostname - yoursite.co.uk

home IT node --> assign hostname - yoursite.it

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the Runway package, which happened to solve this issue, but not exactly what I was looking for.